# Are Draconic Heritage and the Dragonblood subtype equal?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, feat-qualifications

If a feat has Draconic Heritage as a requirement, can it be taken by a character with the Dragonblood subtype, or does he necessarily have to take the Draconic Heritage feat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent. Draconic Heritage gives the Dragonblood subtype (see below), but that is not all it does. Feats that require it as a feat *could* have just been written to require the subtype, but Wizards quite explicitly instead references the feat. You must therefore have it to take those feats.

Just a note on the feat. There are three different printings of Draconic Heritage, from *Complete Arcane*, *Dragon Magic*, and *Races of the Dragon*. The ones from *Dragon Magic* and *Races of the Dragon* are equivalent, and both give the Dragonblood subtype. The one from *Complete Arcane* does not, but it was printed before that subtype existed, and is otherwise identical so you should simply use the *Dragon Magic* or *Races of the Dragon* version if either is in play (since those are the books that use the subtype).

Anyway, personally I think this is pretty dumb: Draconic Heritage is a weak feat, and the Draconic feats that require it are also fairly weak, so I don’t see much reason to have to jump through all these hoops. Were I DM I’d just OK it. Probably wouldn’t even get hung up on the Dragonblood subtype either.

Comment: I just needed to know because there's a feat I wanted that needs Draconic Heritage as a prerequisite; I guess I'll just see if my DM will let me take the feat on account of being a Spellscale.